# What effective build in Torchlight 2 will enable me to see the most skills in play?

Tags: torchlight-2

Just started playing Torchlight 2. I only play to play through the game once, and so ideally I'd like to see as much variety in the game as I possibly can.

What's the most effective class and build that will enable me to:

- employ a mix of ranged and melee combat
- use a diverse range of skills, ideally from different trees

Answer (score 1):

Engineer fits your class :

1. Melee with 2-H weapon.
2. Summon different kind of little robot
3. Ranged with Canon.

each weapon have their own skill tree. . .